# Display custom attribute in the product catalog grid

Tags: magento2

I created, with InstallData.php, a custom product attribute, with the right options so I can see it in the columns in the catalog product list.

However, is there a way to make it displayed in the grid without to have to select it in the columns list?

```
 $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'special_percentage',
                [
                    'type' => 'decimal',
                    'label' => 'Discount percentage',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'default' => 0,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => '',
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'system' => true,
                    'show_in_grid' => true
                ]
            );
```

Comment: I have added a custom attribute(Name: Warehouse, along with three values) on my sales order grid. if order placed I need able to edit that attribute values, like eg. this order assigned for this warehouse like that. is possible can i edit what i need?   source : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334

Answer (score 2):

You can try to replace `'show_in_grid' => true`  with

```
'is_used_in_grid' => true,
'is_visible_in_grid' => true
```

and maybe `'is_filterable_in_grid' => true` if you want it filtering.

Comment: Same thing. I tried with another custom attribute, already set-up, and changed these values in the DB.  Same result: it adds it to the list of column but not display it directly, I have to select it. May be its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the `catalog_eav_attribute` table in your database.

I think it should have a column like `show_in_grid` or something similar.

You can add this to the array when creating the attribute. Setting it to 1 or true should then automatically show the attribute in the products grid.

For example, if the column is `show_in_grid`:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'test_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Test Attribute',
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'show_in_grid' => true
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Infortunately, that's not working, I still have to check it in the columns list. I will add my code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this option

```
'is_used_in_grid'=>1
```

I have tested in `Magento2.0.8` it works fine.